# Why did Jotaro's Star Platinum's punch destroy DIO's The World?

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure

Towards the end of episode 48 of Star Crusaders, Dio kicks at Jotaro who uses Star Platinum to punch The World's shin. Star Platinum's fist ends up cracking, but then The World's entire body ends up cracking, killing DIO in the process.

How could this simple punch kill The World?

Answer (score 4):

Remember when Joseph and Avdol meet Jotaro in jail and told him that Stands were a manifestation of life force? That's the same principle of hamon and that's the reason DIO isn't immune to them.

[here's the explication in youtube](https://youtu.be/cQDzFMdidXs?t=357)

And for completion sake i'll add a quote from the author itself:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

/TLDR
So basically Jotaro out clevered a very arrogant Dio who actually had the power to (even before the JoeStar blood power up) wipe the floor with Jotaro. Then there was the stoptime: though Star Platinum had better precision and growth potential, Dio had way more exp using the World so he could use stoptime more and to a better degree of diversity and effectiveness. That being said Jotaro would be left with his wit and the precision advantage of The World to go for the win by hitting Dio on his weakened left side(sated by Dio as being weaker due to the effects of fusing with the powerful hamon user Jonathon JoeStar). Why would he know this: I chalk it up to Star Platinum's almost X-ray like vision, perceiving minute details and faults that would otherwise be overlooked.

In continuing Joseph was noted to be able to use hamon subconsciously and in everyday encounters. Why couldn't Jotaro, the splitting image of a youthful and rebellious Joseph do the same.[image: Edit: Seems someone had the same reference]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can see that Dio was weakened after he got thrown off of the Road Roller because Jotaro hit his legs.

Second of all Dio mentioned that his left side is weaker than his right side from fusing with Jonathan's body. The leg Star Platinum punched was on his left side too. That's why his body crumbled from the left side upwards.

Comment: Jotaro doesn't know how to use Hamon, so this wouldn't make sense either

Answer (score 1):

When DIO stole Jonathan's body, his left side was weaker due to Jonathan's body not being a vampire. When we see that Jotaro punches DIO in the shin, DIO uses his left leg. His left side wasn't healed yet, and when he kicks him, Jotaro sees the opening and pulls all his power into his fist. See, the more Jotaro gets mad, the more calculated he is. In part 1, DIO uses anger to successfully make Jonathan mad enough to punch him in the boxing match, and to be able to dodge his attacks when Jonathan dashes into the building, shouting "DIO...!" So that's the full demonstration of that.

Answer (score 1):

1. Dio pissed him off.
2. Jotaro saw almost all his friends die.
3. You could see his hand crunching when Joseph died that means he was pissed off.
4. He also said that at the end.
5. If dio didn't kill all his friends, he would of been on the winning side for a few reasons. The first reason is due to DIO having vampiric strength. The second is that DIO had the road roller, and the road roller was still on the ground. If DIO could carry the road roller, he could throw it at Jotaro, and Jotaro would mostly die because his Combat Precision (retconned by fans in the Kira Beatdown) would not longer work, as he can't use Combat Precision forever. Either way, Jotaro would lose because the blue eyes are weaker than the road roller. Plus DIO's strength is the same strength as Combat Precision that leaves Jotaro out in the open that makes DIO summon the world and strike him through the stomach. All this was because DIO pissed him off, as he said at the end of the DIO battle.